# X2VNC is having trouble capturing my cursor

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, firefox

I have a Linux box "L" and a Windows laptop "W"  side by side.  I use x2vnc on L and TightVNC server on W in order to allow one mouse and keyboard (plugged into L) to control both of them.  This setup has worked for many years.  A one pixel wide window is created on the left edge of L's screen, and mousing into it sends it over to W where it seamlessly appears on the right edge of that screen.

Usually.

Lately, I've been having problems.  It seems that when Firefox (3.0.13) is the active window, the cursor will sometimes, but not always, bounce off the left edge and leave me on L.  I cannot reliably make it either happen or not happen.  Specifically, it looks like the cursor is vanishing and then reappearing near the center of L's screen.  When I have other windows active it does not seem to happen, but I cannot say with confidence that it *never* has.

Every time this happens, a message is written by x2vnc to the console where it's running.  It's the same message that it prints the first time it makes a successful connection.  When the mouse is seamlessly passed over correctly, no message is printed.  The message is as follows:

> x2vnc: VNC authentication succeeded
>      x2vnc: Desktop name "Windows_Machine"
>      x2vnc: Connected to VNC server, using protocol version 3.3
>      x2vnc: VNC server default format:
>      screen[0] pos=1004
>      Xinerama detected, x2vnc will use screen 1.
>      x2vnc: pointer multiplier: 1.240917
>      x2vnc: VNC server supports protocol version 3.8 (viewer 3.3)

L is running Gnome 2.22.3 on top of Ubuntu 2.6.24.24.
W is running Windows XP Professional SP3.

I've not yet actually looked at the VNC traffic, so that will be my next step if no one here can offer advice.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but it looks like you need to try [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/), which does exactly what you need (share one mouse and keyboard with different PC's).

Comment: I did consider that.  The problem is not bad enough that I feel compelled to switch technologies, but I do agree that's definitely something to watch.  It also would be a little cleaner in terms of both OS's being on the same page.